# WordPress: Iterate through posts based on array of categories

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to loop through posts based on an **array of categories**?

I would like to loop through an array of categories and then display those posts based on the category they are a part of. Posts can be part of two categories: ie. Category 1 and Category 2. Ideally posts from Category 1 would be in its own `<div>` and posts from Category 2 would be in its own `<div>`.

Instead, my code currently displays ALL posts from both category 1 and category 2.

```
<?php
$args  = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 25,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => array(1,2), 
    'post_type'       => 'page',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

    $posts = get_posts($args); 
        foreach ($posts as $post) :
        ?>
          <div class="category">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                  <div class="person">
                    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200)); ?>
                    <p class="name"><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
                  </div>
             </a>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach;
?>
```

What could I be missing? Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
I've updated my code below, but it is still showing all posts that belong to any of the categories in the array. Ideally, there would be two divs, one for "Category 1" with all "Category 1" posts and one for "Category 2" with all "Category 2" posts.

```
<div class="category">
  <?php
  $posts = get_posts($args);

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($posts); ++$i) {
        $post = $posts[$i]; ?>
        <div class="person">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(array(200,200)); ?>
            <p class="name"><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
          </a>
        </div> 
      <?php
      } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: To do what you want, you have to loop through the posts twice;  once for each category.  Your sample has only one loop.

Comment: @Michael, is there a way to loop based on the length of the `category` array? Like with a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop? I want to also make sure that this works for any number of categories.

Comment: for ($i = 0;  $i < count($posts);  ++$i) { $post = $posts[$i]; ... }

Comment: @Michael I've implemented the for loop-- thanks! But how do I get it to print out items from "Category 1" and then items from "Category 2" in separate divs?